# Which of the Ubuntu versions suitable for Toshiba Harman/Kardon?

Tags: system-installation

I am presently running a Windows 7 32bit operating system, and I just decided to start using Ubuntu as suggested by a friend. I could not install Windows 7 64 because my computers specifications did not meet. I am not sure if its the  same case with Ubuntu, or is there any guarantee that my 1.50GB Ram and 60GB hard diskcan run it?

Comment: Do you plan to replace Windows with Ubuntu or have them both on the same system?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find out is to just try it.

1. [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (pick the 32bit option, obviously)
2. [Burn it to a USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
3. And then boot to it. Pick the Try Ubuntu option when asked and find out what does and doesn't work. If it seems like a viable system, you can install.